# how to get the xml element with namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xml-namespaces, xmldocument

I recently started learning xml, xpath, xmldocuemtn in c#.

I have an xml as shown bellow..namespaces is confusing me a lot

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
   xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
   xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
   xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<Worksheet ss:Name="Pricing">
</Worksheet>
<Worksheet ss:Name="Order">
</Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Here is my c# code..

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(ExcelFilePath);
```

Can you tell me how i can get Worksheet elemet with ss:Name attribute='Pricing'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`XmlNamespaceManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager(v=vs.110).aspx) to provide namespaces:

```
var namespaceMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
namespaceMgr.AddNamespace("x", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet");
namespaceMgr.AddNamespace("ss", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet");
var node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//x:Worksheet[@ss:Name='Pricing']", namespaceMgr);
```

Note that prefixes for namespaces not must match those from XML - the value of namespace counts. So, for example, I've defined `ss` as in XML, but default (root) namespace I've named `x` - it does not matter as long as its value is the same.

To be more strict, you can change XPath to `/x:Workbook/x:Worksheet[@ss:Name='Pricing']` of course.